# infinite scroll loading constantly with Masonry.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

i am using the following code to use Masonry.js and infinite scroll.

```
<div id="container_div">
content to be loaded
</div>

<div id="page-nav">
<?php
$load = 0;
$load++;
print"<a href='gems_ajax_load.php?userid={$userid}&load={$load}''>next</a>"; ?>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
var $container = $('#masonry_container');
$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
debug :true,
loading: {
  finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
  img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
}
},
// trigger Masonry as a callback
function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements );
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
}
);
</script>
```

The problem I am havins is that the Infinite scroll is loading everytime I scroll, no matter where i am on the page. as soon as i touch the scroll, it will load more content, which is just not practical. any ideas?

also when it does load more content, the gif and loading text appear in the top left of the `#masonry_container` when they should show at the bottom of the page surely?

EDIT:
as requested here is my enitre code for that page. It's still in development so please ignore any redundant stuff!

```
<?php
include_once"global.php"; 
include_once"header.php";
?>
<head>
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<!---<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>-->

<script>

function likeGem(id,userid,classname)
{
 $.ajax({

 type: "GET",
 url: 'ajaxrequests.php?action=gemlike',
 data: "id=" + id + "&userid=" + userid, 
 success: function(data) {
       // data is ur summary
      $(classname).html(data);
      console.log(classname);
 }

});

}
</script>
<style>
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
.postcard_create_div input[type="text"]{
    width: 100%;
height: 30px;
border: #CACACA 3px solid;
margin: 3px;
padding: 2px;
}
.postcard_create_div p {
margin:5px;
}
.postcard_create_div textarea{
width:100%;
margin:3px;
}
.postcard_create_desc{
margin: 15px;
padding: 10px;
background: #F37A7A;
line-height: 20px;
font-size:13px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
.postcard_create_div .small_text{
font-size: 10px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
.item { width: 315px;   float: left;min-height:300px;border:1px solid black;margin-    bottom:20px;border-radius: 4px;background:#FFFFFF;}
#masonry_container{padding:20px;height:auto;}

.interact_gem i{
margin:0 4px;
transition:color 0.5s;
}
.fa-heart-o:hover{
color:red;
}
.fa-comment-o:hover{
color:blue;
}
.fa-check-square-o:hover{
color:green;
}
#infscr-loading{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
</style>

</head>

    <div id="header_sub_menu">

    <span class="open-popup-link"><a href="#start-new-convo" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out" >Create a Gem</a></span>

    </div>  
<div style="margin: 30px auto 10px auto;width: 60%;text-align:center;"><p> <img class="pullup" src="css/images/diamond.png"></p>

</div>

<?php
?>
<div id="start-new-convo" class="white-popup mfp-with-anim mfp-hide">
    <p style="font-weight:600;text-align:left;">Create a Gem</p>
    <div class="postcard_create_desc">
            Every Journey has a story. Everyone's story is different and there's always Hidden Gems to be found. 

    </div>
    <div class="postcard_create_div" style="width:90%;margin:auto;text-align:left;">
        <form>
            <p><input placeholder="Where is it?"type="text" name="dest_name"></p>
            <p> <input placeholder="When did you go?" type="text" name="visit_date"></p>
            <p> <textarea placeholder="What's so special?" name="details"></textarea></p>
            <p style="font-size:12px;"><input type="radio" name="private">Private Gem?<br /><span class="small_text" >A private Gem will only be visible to you and your followers</span></p>
            <p style="text-align:right;"><input type="submit" value="Create Gem"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="masonry_container" class="js-masonry ">
  <?php

 $get_gems = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gems ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 0,2");
 $gem_count_up = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gems");
 $nbr = mysqli_num_rows($gem_count_up);

     while($gems = mysqli_fetch_array($get_gems)){ 
        $get_gem_activity = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gem_activity WHERE gem_id = '{$gems['id']}'");
        $check_likes = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gem_likes WHERE userid = $userid AND gem_id = '{$gems['id']}'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($check_likes) > 0){$gem_liked_status = "<i style='color:red;' class='fa fa-heart regtooltip' title='Gem Liked'></i>";}else{$gem_liked_status = "<i class='fa fa-heart-o regtooltip' title='Like this Gem'></i>";}

            print"
            <div class='item'>                  
                <p style='padding: 7px 0 4px 4px;border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(185, 174, 174);font-weight: 600;'>{$gems['gem_name']}</p>
                <p style='text-align:center;'><img style='height:165px;max-width:248px;' src='css/images/{$gems['gem_picture']}'></p>
                <p class='interact_gem' style='padding:3px;'> ";?>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="likeGem(<?php print"{$gems['id']},{$ir['userid']},gem_like_holder_{$gems['id']}";?>)"><span id="gem_like_holder_<?php print"{$gems['id']}";?>" ><?php print"{$gem_liked_status}";?></span></a>
                    <?php print"
                    <i class='fa fa-comment-o regtooltip' title='Comment on Gem'></i>
                    <i class='fa fa-check-square-o regtooltip' title='Mark as Found'></i></p>
                <p style='font-size: 10px;font-weight: 800;text-align: right;padding-top: 2px;padding-right: 2px;'>{$gems['gem_date']}</p>
                <p style='margin-top:12px;padding: 7;font-size: 13px;'>".truncate($gems['gem_body'],100)."</p>
                <p class='regtooltip' title='{$gems['created_date']}' style='margin-top:15px;padding: 5px;border-bottom: 1px solid;font-size: 12px;color:#ADACAC;'><img style='height: 30px;vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 5;' src='".get_display_picture($gems['gem_userid'])."'><span style='font-weight:600;'>".get_username($gems['gem_userid'])."</span> created a new Gem</p>

                ";

                while($gem_activity = mysqli_fetch_array($get_gem_activity))
                {
                    $gem_activity_text = "";
                    if($gem_activity['activity_type'] == "like"){$gem_activity_text = "liked this Gem.";}elseif($gem_activity['activity_type'] == "comment"){$gem_activity_text = "commented.";}

                    print"<p class='regtooltip' title='".time_ago($gem_activity['activity_date'])."' style='padding: 5px;border-bottom: 1px solid;font-size: 12px;color:#ADACAC;'><img style='height: 30px;vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 5;' src='".get_display_picture($gem_activity['userid'])."'><span style='font-weight:600;'>".get_username($gem_activity['userid'])."</span> {$gem_activity_text}  </p>";

                }
                print"



            </div>";
     }
        ?>

</div>






<nav id="page-nav" style="">
<?php
$load = 0;
$load++;
print"<a href='gems_ajax_load.php?userid={$userid}&load={$load}'></a>"; ?>
</nav>
<script>
$(function(){

var $container = $('#masonry_container');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 315,
    gutter : 20
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
  nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  debug : true,
  pixelsFromNavToBottom:100,
  bufferPx: 40, //this
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems); 
    });
  }
);

 });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
          //initiating jQuery
          jQuery(function($) {
            $(document).ready( function() {
              //enabling stickUp on the '.navbar-wrapper' class
              $('#scroll_menu').stickUp();
            });
          });

        </script>
```

EDIT:
I have managed to replicate the issue on an accessible page of my website. http://www.dribbul.com/external_test

Answer (score 0):

Try changing bufferPx, pixelsFromNavToBottom and the appended callback.See below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $container = $('#masonry_container');
$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
debug :true,
pixelsFromNavToBottom:100,
bufferPx: 40, //this
loading: {
 finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
 img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
}
},
// trigger Masonry as a callback
function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements );
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
}
);
 </script>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to solve my issue. It doesn't matter where I am on the page, as soon as i scroll, it loads more content. I could be at the the very top and scrolling up (in google chrome getting the bounce effect) and it will still load more content

Comment: Try changing the masonry callback. See my edit above

Comment: sorry, this still appear to have no effect. I have played about with the bufferpx and can get it so that you can scroll down maybe a 1/8th (and that's not accurate as the page grows longer with pretty much every sctoll) of the page without it grabbing more content, but that is as far as it will go.

Comment: Then I guess one would need more code or a jsfiddle to see your issue. One other thought is to add and play with 'pixelsFromNavToBottom:'

Comment: ive added a link to my websit where you can see this in action. many thanks